# How to update a Julia plot?

Tags: julia

When updating a figure in Julia, how to do it without the plot window grabbing the focus?

Let's say I have the following code:

```julia
using Plots

pyplot()

n = 100
x = collect(range(0, pi, length = n))

for i = 1:30
    y = sin.(x) .+ 0.1 * randn(100)

    plot(x, y, show=true)
    sleep(0)
end
```

When run, the window that displays the plot will grab the focus every time the plot is updated, preventing me from doing anything useful.

How can I update the plot without the window being activated? This would be used for example for monitoring a program in the background.

Comment: I'm not an Plots.jl expert but maybe you can try `plot!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy solution would be to open an empty figure window, arrange it on your desktop however the way you want and reuse it for the next plots. Reusing the same figure window is the default in `Plots.jl`. Here is how the solution looks.

```
using Plots
pyplot() # or another backend

plot() # this will open the plot window app and steal the focus once
# arrange the window however the way you want, put it in another monitor etc.

for i = 1:30
   plot(rand(3,3), show=true, reuse=true) # reuse=true is not necessary since it is already the default
   sleep(0.1)
end
```

Since the same application window will be used again, the plot window will no longer steal focus.

As far as I know, *the very first window* will steal the focus (I think this is not really an issue in your use case), since it is created by another application process. This is the default behavior in most desktop environments. Some desktop environments may allow to change this default.

As a side note, instead of a for loop to regularly update your plot, you can use [`Timer`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Timer-Tuple%7BFunction,Real%7D) events in Julia, which makes things easier and likely to be more efficient.

Comment: This still steals the focus on a macOS v10.14.3 with Julia v1.1.0.

Comment: This steals the focus on an Ubuntu 16.04 with Julia v1.1.0.

Comment: then that's a pyplot bug

Comment: Several users reported similar issues on matplotlib repo. Although it works as expected on my computer with Gnome 3.30 and matplotlib 2.2.2. Can you try with `GR` backend? Can you also check what version is your `matplotlib`?

Comment: @hckr - Thanks, with the `GR` backend it does not steal the focus.